# Struggle connecting HTML/CSS - WebStorm

Tags: html, css, linker, webstorm

This might look a bit stupid, but I cannot seem to connect my HTML to my external CSS stylesheet.

[image: Picture of my codes / directory]

It doesn't change the color of my text. I have tried different CSS commands but nothing seems to work. Help would be greatly appreciated haha...

Answer (score 1):

Your css file names is style.css not "styles.css" the mistake is in your href link

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the wrong file name on your href by mistake. Just change it to style.css like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```